# ASP.NET Usercontrol client side name not resetting after being renamed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a usercontrol in an ASP.net website which client side id was "contact_us" with the ct00 etc, but I have renamed the usercontrol to "feedback", cleaned, rebuilt, published and recycled the app pool and still the name "contact_us".

Does anyone have any idea why the client side name is not reflecting its server side name after being renamed?

This is an important issue which I need to resolve (client not happy).

```
public partial class Contact_Us: TransactionUserControl
{
    #region Public ...

public partial class Feedback : TransactionUserControl
{
    #region Public ...
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All very odd

Try manually deleting content at the following locations

*Temp ASP.Net files*

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

(replace v2.0.50727 with version of asp.net - or better do all)

*Website Cache*

On my machine is at

```
C:\Documents and Settings\[your logon]\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
```

Also check your page directive is referencing your new code behind file and not still the old one for some reason

I've occasionally had the wrong inherit attribute - it's not automatically changed on changing name of file

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Feedback.ascx.cs" 
       Inherits="Feedback" %>
```

Also - I would manually delete all dlls before publish - even though I know the clean solution should do that for you

Comment: This actually done the job! Thankyou for all your help and thanks for the other suggestions guys!  It couldve been any of them, but for me it seemed to be a caching issue :)

Answer (score 1):

This id depends on the ID you used when USING the control not on the name of the class. Check the usage not the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It may not have been renamed in the [filename].aspx.designer.cs file I would check that its correctly named there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, when I read this I seriously thought this would be the answer, I checked and unfortunately it is set to the new name.  And strangely, the old name is referenced no where in my project.  Is there any hidden cache in .NET where the old name could be hiding?